# Is there an easy way to use DSR of Nvidia for a higher resolution than the native resolution of the monitor for everything except games?

Tags: windows, display, nvidia, nvidia-dsr

Previously, when I tried turning DSR settings on, my games decided to apply those higher resolutions even though I was already GPU bottlenecked at the native or even lower resoltions and the frame rates were nothing to brag about even at such low settings.

I thought I could at least use those higher resolutions while reading/writing or watching things since they don't need much GPU power anyway, but I'm not sure if I could do this relatively practically.

I use Windows 10 if it matters.

Comment: Practically you should only use the monitor's native resolution. And NVIDIA DSR has practically no impact on resources. What's your question exactly, if you practically have one?